# getch() exception in Enter and Backspace keys

Tags: c++

I want to get some characters except Enter and Backspace, with getch() method.

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char passwd[20];
    char ch = 'x';
    cout << "Enter Password: ";
    int i = 0;

    while(ch != '\n') 
    {
        ch = getch();
        passwd[i] = ch;
        cout << (char)254; // write dots instead of password that user entered
        i++;
    }
    passwd[i] = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

My code gets Enter and Backspace, but I don't want those. I do make exceptions for these two Keys.

I want to write a code to get password from user and write * instead of them.

I'm using C++.NET Console application.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check for them using simple `if` statements?

Comment: thanks, but I checked before asking question. it doesn't work.

Comment: It might be, that \r is also returned in windows. By the way: Its not a good idea to mix up c-style io (`getch`) and c++-style io (`coud`), especially if a buffer is involved (in your code the `cout`-output is not even flushed.

Comment: "I checked before asking question. it doesn't work" - maybe that's what your question should be about.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; )
{
    int ch = getch();
    if (ch == '\b')
        i = std::max(0, i - 1);  // Backspace, go back a character
    else if (ch == '\r')
        continue;  // Continue loop for unwanted special characters
    else if (ch == '\n')
        break;  // End loop at newline
    else
        passwd[i++] = ch;  // Add character to string
}
passwd[i] = '\0';  // Terminate string
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
while(ch != '\n') 
{
    ch = getch();
    if(ch !='\n' && ch!='\r')
    {
        passwd[i] = ch;
        cout << (char)254; // write dots instead of password that user entered
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char str[100],c=' ';
int i=0;
printf("\n Enter the password [max length 10] : ");
while (i<=100){
    str[i]=getch();
    c=str[i];
    if(c==13) break;
    else if(c=='\b') printf("\b \b");
    else printf("*");
    i++;
}
str[i]='\0';
i=0;
printf("\n");
printf("\n Your password is : %s",str);
return 0;
}
```